# UIView inheritance for multiple UIView in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I'm trying to build a simple iOS app that will simply roll dice with a different number of sides (d20, d12, etc...)

I'd like to create a view that I will re-use multiple times in the same UIViewController, as seen here: http://cl.ly/image/2s30353F3V1K (the only thing that changes is the # of sides)

What I can't figure out is how to properly create the UI element in the storyboard without simply copying and pasting the ContainerView's embeded object for each different number of sides.

Is there an easy way to sub class this properly? I'm new to iOS storyboards and was trying to use OO principles.

Comment: That looks like a perfect situation to use a UITableView.

Comment: Why not make your Die View controller smart enough to handle _any_ desired number of sides? That way, you tell it at instantiation time how many sides there are and _it_ configures its own interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a `DieViewController`, but you need the different instances to have different number of sides.

```
@interface DieViewController
…
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger numberOfSides;
…
@end
```

The question is how to communicate the proper number of sides to each contained instance. This is where the embed segue comes in. In the storyboard, set the storyboard embed segue identifier to something unique (I'll use `6SidedDie`). Finally, in `ViewController` add a `-prepareForSegue:sender:`

```
@@implementation ViewController
…
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"6SidedDie"]) {
        DieViewController *dieViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        dieViewController.numberOfSides = 6;
    }
}
…
@end
```

of course, you can mix this up to allow for lots of dice. Here is code which could handle the identifiers `6SidedDie` and `10SidedDie`.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier hasSuffix:@"Die"]) {
        DieViewController *dieViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        if ([segue.identifier hasPrefix:@"6Sided"]) {
            dieViewController.numberOfSides = 6;
        } else if ([segue.identifier hasPrefix:@"10Sided"]) {
            dieViewController.numberOfSides = 10;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

You can use the `self.viewControllers` array to access the content in the `DieViewController` instances.

```
DieViewController *dieViewController = self.viewControllers[0]; // The first die view controller

if (dieViewController.numberOfSides == 6) {
    // This is the six sided die.
}
```

NOTE: `self.viewControllers` will not be ordered. You will need to check `numberOfSides` to see which type of die this is.

Comment: This makes complete sense.  But how do I bind the controls to the DieViewController? In the image I link to I have 4 container views, and they all link to the same UIView that has 4 objects (2 labels, button, and stepper). How do I bind those 4 objects to the view controller?

Comment: That makes sense to loop through, thanks. Would I then need to manually bind the objects in CODE vs. doing it on the storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question clearly but I have an idea

First, you get an instant of UIViewController

```
YourViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Identifier"];
[vc methodToChangeTheSideProperty:(NSString *)side];
CGRect frame = vc.view.frame;
//change frame of the view as you want
...
...
vc.view.frame = frame;
```

Then, add the view of your controller to container you want to show it

```
[yourViewContainer addSubview:vc.view];
```

Comment: Would I think have to manually connect the bindings of the labels, stepper and button?

Comment: You just need create the `DieViewController` only one time. Use the code above to create how many instant as you need, then call `methodToChangeTheSideProperty` to change text in labels.